# CakePhp Logout problems

Tags: cakephp, logout

I'm having an issue with 'logout' function. The problem is that when i'm logged out i still can get back to previous pages in Browser.

```
public function logout(){
      $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

Please could anyone help.

Comment: When you click back, can you try refreshing the page to see if it still works.

Comment: Thats just the browser cache, disable the cache and it will work just fine. By default I call sth like [disableCache()](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-shim/blob/2.x/Controller/ShimController.php#L63) for all dynamic CakePHP pages.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'm having another problem is that my uploaded files into the webroot folder can be accesible even though the user is not logged in ! :/ Could u help me